# Itext c# - Error convert html to pdf/a [the smask key is not allowed in xobjects ]

Tags: c#, itext, pdfa

I have html, it has a gif image in base64. The transparency and CMYK colors were removed in the image.
But when converting HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf (html, pdfDocument, properties), an error occurs: the smask key is not allowed in xobjects

My code is

```
function test(){
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new PdfWriter(ms))
    {
        using (var profileIcmFs = new FileStream(profileIcm, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var pdfDocument = new PdfADocument(
                                                                    writer,
                                                                    PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B,
                                                                    new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", profileIcmFs)
                                                                )
                  )
            {
                var document = new iText.Layout.Document(pdfDocument);

                var font = iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(timesFont, iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
                var fontBd = iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(timesBdFont, iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);

                var properties = new ConverterProperties();
                properties.SetBaseUri("");
                var fontProvider = new iText.Layout.Font.FontProvider();
                fontProvider.AddFont(font.GetFontProgram());
                fontProvider.AddFont(fontBd.GetFontProgram());

                properties.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);
                HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, pdfDocument, properties);              
                document.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">

<div>
 <div>the smask key is not allowed in xobjects</div>
 <br/>
 <div />
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the images present on the HTML file?

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t post the image, consider that it is forbidden. If you remove the image, then everything is fine.
A image created in c # is converted normally. If you want, offer me a image, I will try it. I can’t provide mine image.

Comment: Well, if an *image created in c # is converted normally* while your forbidden image is not, then there is an issue with that forbidden image. If you can't share it, we cannot help identify the issue beyond pure guesswork. Most likely transparency was not removed completely, e.g. while there probably is no transparent pixel anymore, the image itself still states that it contains transparency information.

Comment: Well, I will share the shortened HTML file, it also gives an error. Which is better? I especially never used file hosting, but then I did not find "attach file"

Comment: I understood. Posted in post

Comment: this is the information I get about the image you have posted: "PNG image data, 875 x 137, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced", so it feels like the alpha channel is still there.

Comment: Thank. I'll try to handle this case

Answer (score 0):

Hello I've ran on same problem and I believe the error is because on PDF/A conformance, transparency is not allowed. Check if your image have some transparency on it. And check the PDF/A restrictions as there are more

Comment: No, I'm using HtmlRenderer.WinForms.
I used the RenderToImage method which doesn't support transparent background. For the transparent background, I replaced it with the RenderToImageGdiPlus method. Perhaps this will help you.